# What does "loop" mean in "loop device"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

This maybe a linguistic question. I have checked the [loop device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) on Wikipedia. It is just for mounting files as block device. But what does "loop" mean here? Its usage here is totally bizarre to me. I am not a native English speaker. So could someone explain this jargon to me in plain English?  :)

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback

Comment: I guess you should be able to translate the english page back in to your native language!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's short for "[loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback)".

Comment: Why is it called "loopback" though? I can see two parallels: Loopback of the network device (i.e having some word play), or loop back in the sense that the driver asks back into the file-system again for the file to map into. What meaning is correct?

Comment: It's the latter one. Normally a request would go `userspace -> VFS -> block device layer`, but when the block device driver is loop, it goes `userspace -> VFS -> loop device -> VFS -> block device`. So it loops back to a higher level.

Comment: As far as I know the term originated in the depths of the telecom industry (and probably dates back to telegraphs). See mmonem's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is also known as a [disk image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image). I guess because driver calls to the image get passed along to the underlying driver of the physical disk. There is no actual loop involved; it is an additional level to a driver stack which is already several layers deep.

(I've written an encrypted disk image driver, and I find the "loopback" terminology incorrect and confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this term comes from the communication realm when sometimes it is needed to test the communication system by simulating a peer using a proxy circuit loop.

The concept came also to UNIX networking where loopback network interfaces do not send network  traffic to the medium.

The same concept in file systems loop means that the file system driver does not really goes through the hard disk IO stack and, instead, ends using a *plain* disk image file for IO.